# Are there methods for mapping out a program's flow?

Tags: architecture

I am writing a modeling script that is composed of many functions, and I'm trying to keep a document going that looks something like this:

```
build_model(data, outcome_variable) returns(model)
     clean_data(data, outcome_variable) returns(cleaned_data)
        clean_character_data(data, outcome_variable) returns(data_with_chars_cleaned)
        clean_numeric_data(data_with_chars_cleaned, outcome_variable) returns(data_with_chars_and_numerics_cleaned)
     train_model(clean_data, outcome_variable) returns(model)
```

Only my modeling script is quite a bit more complicated. Basically I am wondering how people usually keep track of which functions are calling other functions, and expressing this in terms of inputs and outputs.

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but I read the source code to keep track of what is calling what. It is the only definitive reference.

Comment: And stack traces.  The source and stack traces.  An exception tends to focus the mind.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Self-describing variable and function names help at the function level, i.e. writing:

```
data_with_chars_cleaned = clean_character_data(...)
```

makes it unnecessary to add a comment `# returns ...`. Keeping functions small makes it easier to come up with a descriptive name.

(2) Good abstractions make it unnecessary to keep all the minutiae in your head. Everything a function does "should" be at the same level of abstraction, e.g. here every statement in the function is at the same abstraction level:

```
def build_model(data):
    cleaned_data = clean_data(data)
    model = create_new_model()
    trained_model = train_model(model, cleaned_data)
```

When *building* *a* *model* I shouldn't need to know the details of *how* the data is cleaned, *how* the model is created, or *how* the model is trained.

Compare the above to:

```
def build_model(data):
    # clean numeric data
    cleaned_data = CleanDataConatiner()
    for item in data:
        if item not in NaN, None, -Inf:
            cleaned_data.add(item)
    # clean character data
    ...
    model = create_new_model()
    trained_model = train_model(model, cleaned_data)
```

It is said that your brain can only keep 4-7 items in your working memory at any one time, so keeping functions at an abstraction level that allows you to have only 4-7 loops/branches/calls per function will make it easier to grok.

There are also graphical tools that will build e.g. call graphs for you depending on your language.  Depending on your language you can also write code that traces invocations yourself.  I see both of these as more of debugging tools than as a program flow visualization tools -- imho, visualizing the data flow is usually more fruitful when trying to understand a system.

Comment: There is a saying, usually attributed to Fred Brooks: "Show me your flowcharts [algorithms] and conceal your tables [data structures], and I shall continue to be mystified. Show me your tables, and I won't usually need your flowcharts; they'll be obvious." Maybe the same can be said for control-flow / data-flow.